# Creating QuickTabs programmatically not working

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm trying to create some QuickTabs programmatically like it's documented [on the website](http://drupal.org/node/332895), but for some reason, my code bellow doesn't generate QuickTabs at all!
What do I do wrong or am I looking at the wrong documentation here?

```
function quicktabsmenu_block_info() {
  $blocks['quicktabsmenu'] = array(
    'info' => t('Dynamic QuickTabs menu'), 
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

function quicktabsmenu_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'quicktabsmenu':
       //set tab content
        $block['subject'] = t('Syndicate');
        $block['content'] = _create_quicktabs();
        return $block;
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

function _create_quicktabs() {
  $tabs['tabcontent'] = array(
    'title' => t('Tab 1'),
    'type' => 'freetext',
    'text' => t('Free text'),
  );
  $quicktabs['qtid'] = 'my_new_quicktabs';
  $quicktabs['tabs'] = $tabs;
  $quicktabs['style'] = 'Zen';
  $quicktabs['ajax'] = FALSE;;
  $var = theme('quicktabs', $quicktabs);
  return $var;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after some thinking [and searching](http://drupal.org/node/332895#comment-5618872), I managed to solve my own question. All I needed was this:

```
$tabs = array(
   $tabs[] = array(
      'title'   => t('Tab one'),
      'type'    => 'node',
      'nid'     => '24',
      'weight'  => 0,
    ),
    $tabs[] = array(
      'title'   => t('Tab two'),
      'type'    => 'node',
      'nid'     => '23',
      'weight'  => 1,
    ),
);

// Configure the QuickTabs options
$quicktabs_options = array(
   'style'   => 'Bullets',
   'ajax'    => FALSE,
);

$quicktabs_name = 'dynamic_quicktabs_menu';
$quicktabs = quicktabs_build_quicktabs($quicktabs_name, $quicktabs_options, $tabs);
return $quicktabs;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, where have you added this code (I'm new to drupal so would appreciate if you could tell me the filename where this code is to be added)

Comment: Typically you would put this in a module.