# How to add descriptions to quicktabs

Tags: blocks

I would like to know I can add descriptions to quicktabs. Ideally, every tab would have it's own description that gets displayed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can render quicktabs programmatically and where title field, you can add your descriptions. Here is link to manual: [Creating QuickTabs programmatically not working](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56866/creating-quicktabs-programmatically-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [patch](https://drupal.org/node/1032920#comment-4020154) for 6.x version which adds a description functionality to [Quicktabs](https://drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module.

> 1. Admin area has 2 new option for every tab:
>
>    - Description Text
>    - Description Type: Tip or Text
> 2. Front area has default styling for both
>
>    - Tip - simple hoverIn-hoverOut box with default styling.
>    - Text - simple text displayed below the tab title with default styling.

It is not a big patch, with some effort you can take the idea and apply it for the 7.x version.

Comment: thanks but that patch is for 6.x version. Do you think it's compatible with 7.x as well?

Comment: I have completely overlooked that! Sorry :( But it may give you an idea how to implement it for 7.x.