# Creating quicktabs prorgammatically: code worked in D6 not in d7

Tags: 7

I created a custom quicktabs module in drupal 6 that adds a block, and it is working just fine. Before moving it over to drupal 7, I edited the module and info files accordingly, but the module displays no block on `admin/structure/block` and the version of the module doesn't appear on `admin/modules`.

I have added the feeds and their blocks are displaying content and the bids are identical in both versions of the site.

I have read [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56866/creating-quicktabs-programmatically-not-working) and [this](https://drupal.org/node/332895) and even tried [this](https://drupal.org/node/679148), but haven't found the solution. I have run cron and cleared cache when you would be expected to.

If I add a `print_r($tabs)` I get an array with all of the array pieces as designated below for the right days.

**quicktab_custom.info file**

```
name = quicktab custom
description = custom quicktab block for event data
core = 7.x
```

**quicktab_custom.module file**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block().
 * 
 * We want to define a quicktabs block.
 */
function quicktab_custom_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {

switch($op) {
// 'list' shows the items in admin/build/block admin page
// we alsohave: configure, save, view
case 'list':
  $blocks['quicktab_custom_quicktabs'] = array(
    'info' => t('events this week'),
    'cache' => BLOCK_NO_CACHE,
  );
  return $blocks;
  break;
case 'view':

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'quicktab_custom_quicktabs':
     $today = date('D');

      //set tab content
      $tabs[] = array(
        'title' => t($today),
        'type' => 'block',
        'bid' => 'aggregator_delta_feed-14',

      );
      $tabs[] = array(
        'title' => t(date('D',strtotime($today . ' +1 day'))),
        'type' => 'block',
        'bid' => 'aggregator_delta_feed-15',

      );
      $tabs[] = array(
        'title' => t(date('D',strtotime($today . ' +2 day'))),
        'type' => 'block',
        'bid' => 'aggregator_delta_feed-16',

      );
      $tabs[] = array(
        'title' => t(date('D',strtotime($today . ' +3 day'))),
        'type' => 'block',
        'bid' => 'aggregator_delta_feed-17',

      );
      $tabs[] = array(
        'title' => t(date('D',strtotime($today . ' +4 day'))),
        'type' => 'block',
        'bid' => 'aggregator_delta_feed-18',

      );
      $tabs[] = array(
        'title' => t(date('D',strtotime($today . ' +5 day'))),
        'type' => 'block',
        'bid' => 'aggregator_delta_feed-19',

      );
      $tabs[] = array(
        'title' => t(date('D',strtotime($today . ' +6 day'))),
        'type' => 'block',
        'bid' => 'aggregator_delta_feed-20',

      );

      $quicktabs['qtid'] = 'quicktab_custom_quicktabs'; // machine readable name
      $quicktabs['hide_empty_tags'] = TRUE;     // hide tabs that are empty
      $quicktabs['default_tab'] = $today;   // set the default tab
      $quicktabs['tabs'] = $tabs;       // all tabs with content
      $quicktabs['style'] = 'Navlist';      // tabs theme -- originally set to Sky
      $quicktabs['ajax'] = FALSE;       // ajax or not
      $block = array('subject' => '', 'content' => theme('quicktabs', $quicktabs));

      return $block;
      break;
  }
 } 
}
```

Comment: For the rest of my problems, I found the solution here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/56882/27201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this comment on the hook_block() docs](https://api.drupal.org/comment/502#comment-502),

> Drupal 7 doesn't use anymore hook_block(), but it uses a set of new hooks; see [Converting 6.x modules to 7.x](https://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#remove_op) for more details.