# Implementation of quicktab by codes

Tags: 7, blocks

I am trying to add quick tabs from codes. I got the code from here [Creating QuickTabs programmatically not working](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56866/creating-quicktabs-programmatically-not-working) . But noone explains how to implement this , where to add the code. I am trying to add like this.

**test.module**

```
<?php
    function test_menu(){

    $items['test/quicktabs'] = array(
        'title'=> 'quicktabs',
        'page callback' => 'test_quicktabs',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      );
    return $items;
    }

    function test_quicktabs(){
    $tabs = array();

    $tabs[] = array(
      'title' => t('Tab1'),
      'type' => 'freetext',
      'text' => 'Hello wecome to Tab1',
    );
    $tabs[] = array(
      'title' => t('Tab2'),
      'type' => 'freetext',
      'text' => 'Hello wecome to Tab2',
    );
    $tabs[] = array(
      'title' => t('Tab3'),
      'type' => 'freetext',
      'text' => 'Hello wecome to Tab3',
    );

    // Configure the QuickTabs options
    $quicktabs_options = array(
       'style'   => 'Bullets',
       'ajax'    => FALSE,
    );

    $quicktabs_name = 'dynamic_quicktabs_menu';
    $quicktabs = quicktabs_build_quicktabs($quicktabs_name, $quicktabs_options, $tabs);
    return $quicktabs;

    }
?>
```

I am not sure , this is a correct approach . How to implement quicktabs inside other modules?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, As previously i was not using   `'renderer'    => 'quicktabs'`, . Also

```
 $tabs[] = array(
          'title' => t('Tab3'),
          'type' => 'freetext',
          'text' => 'Hello wecome to Tab3',
        );
```

was not working.
Use this working function.

```
function test_quicktabs(){



    $quicktabs_options = array(
        'style'   => 'Basic',
        'ajax'    => FALSE,
        'renderer'    => 'quicktabs',
    );

    $quicktabs_name = 'newinstance';

    $custom_tabs = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Tab 1',
            'contents' => 'tab1',
            'weight' => -10
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Tab2',
            'contents' => 'tab2',
            'weight' => 0
        ));


   return  quicktabs_build_quicktabs($quicktabs_name, $quicktabs_options, $custom_tabs);

}
```

If anyone find better implementation using quicktabs hooks. Please do answer.

Comment: If it provides an answer to the question, please add some description to it.